# How do I check for duplicates and remove them on each data entry in SQL Server, WPF, C#?

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, sql-update

I'm practicing SQL integration in C# by creating a Zoo Management app. Users can input a new name of Zoo to be listed on a ListBox. I want the app to check whether the new zoo is already listed or not (checking for duplicates), and if there is a duplicate, it will remove the newly added zoo.

I can't figure out the SQL query to do that.

Here I create a tiny simulation app to ask about the duplicates removing method.

Table name is `TEST` with just 2 columns `Id` and `Name`.

In the WPF there is a ListBox which lists all names, 2 buttons (`Add` and `Remove` names), and one TextBox to type in the want-to-be added name.

I've tried various methods and I just can't seem to get it to work.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DeleteDuplicateTest.Properties.Settings.DB1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowNames();
    }

    // This is where I got lost
    public void CheckForDuplicates()
    {
    }

    public void ShowNames()
    {
        string query ="select * from TEST";
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConnection);

        using (sqlDataAdapter)
        {
            DataTable names = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(names);
            listNames.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
            listNames.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
            listNames.ItemsSource = names.DefaultView;
        }
    }

    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myTextBox.Text != "") 
        { 
            string query = "Insert into TEST values (@Name)";

            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);

            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", myTextBox.Text);

            sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

            sqlConnection.Close();

            ShowNames();
            CheckForDuplicates();
        }
    }

    private void Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listNames.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            string query = "Delete from TEST where Id=@Name";

            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);

            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", listNames.SelectedValue);

            sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            sqlConnection.Close();

            ShowNames();
            CheckForDuplicates();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do NOT use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: And your description is not consistent. You want your "app to check ... duplicate and remove ..." but you want a "sql query to do that."  Do WHAT? Your struggle because you don't quite have a design in place for what your application is supposed to do. I suggest you write 2 simple use cases first - one for the duplicate situation and one for the non-dup situation. Then figure out how your application should respond for both. THEN write your code. CheckForDuplicates is a post-retrieval/display function so it seems it has no specific db action at this point.